# Conditional gobal variable from config.py based on selection

Tags: python

I use python to display my data analysis in a dashboard.
Until now, I have only presented the data of one project in my dashboard.
In the current version, the program starts of with a main program and calls different pages to be displayed from different modules.
As all pages need some universal variables, like the file path or some imported pandas dataframes, I have defined these variables in a `config.py` module.
By this means, I can import the config.py module in each page module easily and the variables are globally accessible.
In the next version, I want to expand the dashboard to several projects. Therefore, based on the selection of the project, different values should be assigned to the variables in `config.py`.

I have made this little dummy program below to visualise the program structure.
Is there any way that based on the selection in the main program different global variables in the config.py file are defined?

```
# config.py

x = 1
y = 2

''' 
Instead of this fixed assignment, I would like to have here an assignment
of the variables based on the user input, i.e. choice of project:
For example, if project 1 is chosen, then x = 1 and y = 2 
and if project 2 is chosen, then x = 3 and y = 4
Another example: As each project has a different file path for the source data, 
a specific file path depending on the chosen project will be assigned to a file path variable.
'''
```

```
# page.py

import config as cfg

def write(selection):
    print(f'This is project {selection}')
    print(cfg.x)
    print(cfg.y)
```

```
# main.py

import page

selection = input("Project 1 or 2?")
page.write(selection)
```

Maybe there is an easy solution or I have to structure the program completely different.
Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the use case is not clear from the question

Comment: I added a comment to config.py to make my point clearer. Maybe I could be also on the total wrong path and my question makes no sense for an experienced programmer...

Comment: from the comment, I think you want to take input from the user and set this input value as global value for all modules?

Comment: What I want is to define, dependent on the input, specific values as global values for all modules, e.g. each project has a different file path to import data. Based on the user input, a certain file path will be assigned to the file path variable

Comment: As far as I know, people do what you are doing with yaml (or alternative) files. You can check the package `yaml`. There are probably thousands out there.

Comment: does it have to be globals? why not simply use a class which stores the values for you?

Comment: @Andreas @areijman Thanks for your suggestions. I did not know about `yaml`, but similar to the `confiparser`approach suggested below, it seems a good way. The `class` approach is probably the most elegant one. But I still have to read a bit more about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw the two configurations into a config file, and load the variables from there.

## config.ini

```
[1]
stuff = "abc"
more = 123

[2]
stuff = "xyz"
more = 456
```

## config.py

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
```

## main.py

```
import page

selection = input("Project 1 or 2?")
page.write(selection)
```

## page.py

```
from config import config

def write(selection):
    print(f'This is project {selection}')
    print(config[selection]["stuff"])
    print(config[selection]["more"])
```

That said, global variables carry a bit of a bad smell, and often cause headaches further down the line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know about `config.ini` and `configparser`, or the `yaml` package as mentined above. But with your suggestion I can solve my problem. I know that global variables are not perfect. Maybe in a next step I can solve the problem also by using a `config class` and thereby avoiding global variables. However, I still have to read a bit more about classes to implement such an approach...

Comment: Global variables are not bad if you do not change them. If you use them as unique named constants they are totally fine. Globals are considered bad because if you change them at any point it becomes really hard to debug and that you accidentially override them if the name is not unqiue and is used again.

Comment: The globals will be used as unique named constants in my dashboard. Just the value will changed according to the project selcetion.

Answer (score 1):

If you go with a class it should be possible even without changing any additional code.
The only thing you propably need to read about is **init**() which is a method which executes the code in it self if you create the class object.

```
def Config():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2
```

---

```
import Config as cfg
def write(selection):
    print(f'This is project {selection}')
    print(cfg.x)
    print(cfg.y)
```

---

```
import page
selection = input("Project 1 or 2?")
page.write(selection)
```

This way you could even preprocess data differently, depending on where you need it, by simply including a method (class function) to the class.

---

---

Second Example with multiple config values:

```
# config.py
class Config():
    
    def __init__(self, selection):
        self.select_project(selection)
        
    def select_project(self, selection):
        
        if project_name == "1":
            self.x = 3
            self.y = 4
            
        elif project_name == "2":
            self.x = 5
            self.y = 6
```

---

```
# page.py
import Config as cfg
def write(selection):
    cfg_object = Config(selection)
    print(f'This is project {selection}')
    print(cfg_object.x)
    print(cfg_object.y)
```

---

```
# main.py
import page
selection = input("Project 1 or 2?")
page.write(selection)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But how would the values change upon project selection? Do I need to have a spefici class for each project? Or how ill the project-specific variable assignment take place?

Comment: @Mikele adjusted my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks like a very elegant approach!

Comment: @Mikele classes might look confusing at start but they are very powerfull if used correctly, if you have some time looking into them I would highly recommend it.

Comment: I will try to find some time to look more into them...